# No media player plays any sound in Windows 8.1

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, windows-media-player

None of the media players (Winamp, Splayer, etc play any sound, even if the video shows up.

[image]

The system was working properly, and this happened out of the blue. Youtube, on the other hand, works properly.

Does anyone know the cause?

Comment: If you go to the sound control and click to make a ding sound do you hear it?

Answer (score 0):

Check those app's volume in the mixer. They may be muted.